# How do I append "ng-click()" to <img> tags on an array of dynamically added html?

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-click

I'm very new to AngularJS and I'm figuring out how to add an ng-click on all img tag so I can get a display what I click them.

The logic I'm thinking is using angular.foreach to track all the contents of the array with regex and append their src's along with an ng-click.

Here's code for scouring the image links.

```
var rex = /src\=[\"\']?([a-zA-Z0-9 \:\-\#\(\)\.\_\/\;\'\,]+)\;?[\"\']?/ig
var arr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.tasks, function (key, value) {
            while ((arr = rex.exec($scope.tasks[value])) !== null) {
                $scope.test.push(arr[1]);
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index" ng-show="$index == index">
                <div>                        
                    <span text-angular ta-unsafe-sanitizer="true" class="labActWidth" ta-bind ng-model="task.TaskDetails">
                    </span>                       
                </div>
        </div>
```

$scope.tasks Value:

```
 0:TaskDetails:"<p>123456789123456789</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>huhu</p>"
 1:TaskDetails:"<p style="padding-left: 240px;">asdsajdnsalkdjasl</p>"
 2:TaskDetails:"<p>iasjdlaksjdlakjdlsakjdlaksjd</p>"
 3:TaskDetails:"<p>gsub("XCZCX", "ZXCZCXZ");</p>"
 4:TaskDetails:"<p>asd</p>"
 5:TaskDetails:"<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" /></p>"
 6:TaskDetails:"<p style="text-align: right;"><strong>asdasdsadsaa</strong></p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;"><strong>dsadada</strong></p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;"><strong>asdasdsadsa</strong></p><p style="text-align: right;"><strong>dasdasdasd</strong></p><p style="text-align: right;"><em><strong>asdasdasdasdasdas</strong></em></p><p style="text-align: right;"><em><strong>dasdasdasdasd</strong></em></p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;"><em><strong>asdasdasdasdasd</strong></em></p><p style="text-align: right;"><em><strong>asdasdasdasd</strong></em></p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;<img src="data:image/png;base64,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…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" alt="" /></p><p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p><p style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</p>"
 7:TaskDetails:"<p>asdsadsa</p>"
 8:TaskDetails:"<p>asdasdas</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>okoko</p>"
 9:TaskDetails:"<p style="padding-left: 60px;">asdasdasdsadasd</p>"
```

Comment: Where is html? what is the value of `$scope.tasks`?

Comment: You can add ng-click wherever you want. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: @Kenny I edited my question.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure I don't know how to append it on html from database. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Working code for your answer

```
<!-- Hi this is working code for you-->

<div ng-repeat="img in imgArr">
   <img ng-src="img.source" ng-click="openViewer(img.source)" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this works for data not retrieved from database.

Comment: @SlicedBread: it should work if you have correct data inside imgArr.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure if it's okay, could you review my question? I've entered the value of my data above.

Comment: I am unable to understand your actual requirement but if you bind the html you can simply use ng-bind-html="str" and sanitizer library.

Comment: @SlicedBread: $scope.tasks is not showing data in proper format.

Comment: $scope.tasks.vale is your data please confirm

Comment: @SantoshSingh $scope.tasks is my value. My regex is not working.